# python Streamlit update/overwrite column values without blinking

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit

Problem statement:
I have 2 columns on streamlit: one for ticker_symbol and other for it's current value.
I want to update the current_value every second (column2) but the code I have so far first removes the written value of the current_price and then writes the new value. I would like the current_value to be overwritten without being removed at all. This also means the last ticker_symbol in the col has to wait for a long time to show it's current value since the previous value gets removed by st.empty.

What can I do to achieve the goal mentioned above?
Should I not use st.empty ? Are there any other alternatives in streamlit ?

```
import time
import yfinance as yf
import streamlit as st


st.set_page_config(page_title="Test", layout='wide')
stock_list = ['NVDA', 'AAPL', 'MSFT']

left, right, blank_col1, blank_col2, blank_col3, blank_col4, blank_col5, blank_col6, blank_col7, blank_col8, blank_col9, \
blank_col10 = st.columns(12, gap='small')

with left:
    for index, val in enumerate(stock_list):
        st.write(val)


with right:
    while True:
        numbers = st.empty()
        with numbers.container():
            for index, val in enumerate(stock_list):
                stock = yf.Ticker(val)
                price = stock.info['regularMarketPrice']
                # st.write(": ", price)
                st.write(": ", price)
                time.sleep(0.5)
        numbers.empty()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this.

```
with right:

    # The number holder.
    numbers = st.empty()

    # The infinite loop prevents number holder from being emptied.
    while True:
        with numbers.container():
            for index, val in enumerate(stock_list):
                stock = yf.Ticker(val)
                price = stock.info['regularMarketPrice']
                st.write(": ", price)
                time.sleep(0.5)
```

Sample simulation code with random.

```
import time
import streamlit as st
import random


st.set_page_config(page_title="Test", layout='wide')
stock_list = ['NVDA', 'AAPL', 'MSFT']

(left, right, blank_col1, blank_col2, blank_col3, blank_col4,
blank_col5, blank_col6, blank_col7, blank_col8, blank_col9,
blank_col10) = st.columns(12, gap='small')

with left:
    for index, val in enumerate(stock_list):
        st.write(val)


with right:
    numbers = st.empty()
    while True:
        with numbers.container():
            for index, val in enumerate(stock_list):
                price = random.randint(-100, 100)
                st.write(": ", price)
                time.sleep(0.5)
```